# Why are there default accessibility levels in C#?

Tags: c#

Lately, I've been doing some work in Java and C#. In Java, not specifying the accessibility of a class or a class member makes it *package private* (for which no explicit modifier exists). In C#, this is different as [the accessibility always defaults to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) a level that can also be explicitly specified with the corresponding modifier (e.g., `internal` for a top-level class).

C# is such a well designed language, so why does it even contain this feature of defaulting to different levels depending on type and nesting of the types instead of just forcing the user to be explicit? Is there any benefit I don't know about?

Comment: I'd say this is much better in C# than in Java. The default in Java is horribly chosen, and not being able to be explicit about it just makes it worse. It's not clear whether you're saying that you think Java is better or worse - your second paragraph suggests you think it should always be explicit, but your first paragraph seems to suggest you like the way Java works...

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree that C# improved this by adding a "package private" aka "internal" keyword. My point is just: as there is therefore an explicit modifier for each available level, why have a default at all?

Comment: `internal` *isn't* the same thing as "package private" at all - assemblies and namespaces are different. As for having explicit modifiers - some people like being explicit and others don't. It also makes code easier to move around - you can change an internal nested class into an internal top-level class without changing anything, for example.

Comment: So you don't *have* to do it explicitly.. Note that assemblies and packages are not the same: they overlap in some aspects but it's not a 1-on-1 conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is that it is convenient to supply a default access, especially in things like structs where you usually want everything to be public, and often a large proportion of a class will be private.

However, I'd personally like it to be possible to force it to be explicit, as it makes the source code more consistent, and stops you forgetting to make members public - my main gripe is that I often create a new property or method, forget to set it explicitly public, and then when I later come to use it from an external class, get confused because that member doesn't appear in the autocomplete list. Realising what has happened and fixing it takes much more time than just fixing a warning like "access level of x was not explicitly specified".